# How to specify a parameter in an HTTP GET request

Tags: rest, http, get, http-headers, httprequest

I am developing a REST API and I would like to make a GET request that retrieves in JSON format the user specified by "username", like:

```
{
id: "559d7ced2de324e22a78998b"
firstname: "fname"
lastname: "flast"
username: "testpassword"
password: "testusername"
address: "123 road"
city: "washington DC"
state: "california"
zipCode: "2345"
phoneNumber: "234523452345"
email: "email@gmail.com"
}
```

The path is /users, just like: `http://localhost:8080/users`

My question is, how do make a GET request call that specifies the username.

Is it something like this: `http://localhost:8080/users/?username=testusername`?

This is my Java method. I am using Spring REST:

```
/* Get user by username */
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="{username}")
    public User getUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
        return repo.findByUsername(username);
    }
```

Comment: Note that having *password: "testusername"* anywhere, in any layer of your application, means something is really wrong. You should never have a clear password anywhere, never.

Answer (score 0):

It is your right format
http://localhost:8080/users?username=testusername

if you have more than 1 parameter then write

http://localhost:8080/users?username=testusername&email=email_address

Comment: Calling  http://localhost:8080/users?username=testusername returns ALL the users. It's going to the default GET method that returns all users. Is my java method incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. If the client knows the username, you can support a new endpoint

```
GET /users/{username}
```

If the client needs to search the available set of users by username, then you have one method:

```
GET /users
GET /users?username={username}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
    if (username == null) {
        return repo.findAllUsers();
    }
    return repo.findByUsername(username);
}
```